# How do I force my iPhone to obtain a new IP-address?

Tags: iphone, gprs

What is the fastest way to force my iPhone to obtain a new IP-address?

One way to get a new IP-address is to simply restart the iPhone, but that is rather slow. Is there any faster way to obtain a new IP-address?

I'm running iPhone OS 3.0 and I'm getting my Internet connectivity over GPRS.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The quickest way I have found to reset all the network connections (wifi, 3g/edge/gprs) is to go to settings and turn on "Airplane Mode" for a few seconds and then turn it off again. It will reset all network connections.

Settings-->Airplane Mode

I have found this also to help when my phone doesn't connect to 3g in a known 3g area.

Comment: @knorv This is RENEWING IP only, not getting a new IP-address!

Comment: I didn't say it reset the IP, I just said it resets the connections. deddebme is correct in it being up to the carrier/server to give you a new ip. Sometimes you get a new one, sometimes you don't.

Answer (score 1):

Turn wireless off and on again? It may not actually get a new IP as it may just renew the lease.

I don't have a ipod/iphone so I don't know if there is a renew IP button, but i would take a look around any network settings, especially the page on wifi where it says what your current status / connection is (going from memory on my brothers one)

Comment: getting a new NAT ip depends on the DHCP server, not the client, in this case the iPhone.

Comment: That's why I said it may just renew the lease and not get a new ip.

Answer (score 0):

There is definitely a "Renew Lease" button.

Go to Settings, Wi-Fi, click the blue arrow next to a network and you'll see it. You can also tell it to "forget" the current network it's on.

Comment: But OP was using GPRS, not wifi.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, go into the settings and change the wifi setting inside the chosen network from DHCP or whatever to Static. Copy all data except IP address. Take the first 3 sections of your assigned IP and copy them. Ex: IP is 143.23.0.198, copy over 143.23.0. then make up the last 3 didgets, making sure not to use 0,1, or 255. Those are specifically reserved for network tasks. then you should be good. it worked for me.